# How to evaluate this integral? $\int \arctan^{3}(x) \sec^{4} (x) dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

im tring to solve this integral, but i have no idea how to do it:
$$\int \arctan^{3}(x) \sec^{4} (x) dx$$

Comment: Is there a reason you think this function has a nice integral?

Comment: this is my calculus assignmnet, i try u-subtitution, integral by parts, and trigonometric transformation, but i still can not get solution.

Comment: There is a nice approach if it was $\int\tan^3(x)\sec^4(x)\,dx$ but I'm not sure about $\int\arctan^3(x)\sec^4(x)\,dx.$

Comment: Did the original problem say $\tan^{-3}(x),$ perhaps, and you read it as $\arctan^3(x)?$

Comment: it is arctan(x), not 1/tan(x).  and by the way, i thought $arctan(x) = tan^{-1}(x), \frac{1}{tan(x)} = tan(x)^{-1}$ is it correct?

because in my book: it writes $arctan(x) = tan^{-1}(x)$

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica also says very definitively that, with the integrand as $\arctan^{3}(x) \sec^{4} (x)$ , neither the indefinite integral nor the definite integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ has elementary solution.

Comment: Thanks every one, so it maybe a typo for current what i learn intergral methods?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin The definite integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ should be $\infty$, due to the singularity of $\sec$ at $\pi/2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You're right. I was testing with various values like $\pi / 4$ and $\pi/6$ etc, and I miss typed. I basically wanted to say nothing is good all the way up to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maple (using the Risch-Norman algorithm) indicates that the antiderivative is not elementary.

Comment: Thanks, so is it meaning this integral can not be get solution by 'normal' way like basic integral mathods?

Comment: Yes, the methods you learn in calculus class all produce elementary functions when they work.  When the antiderivative is not elementary, they are all doomed to fail.